# Need Help Installing MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, macos, terminal

I have downloaded and stalled the MySQL server 5.5 version via .DMG on my Mac.

But I am confused as to what to do next.  I have the preference settings bundle and it says that the MySQL server is running.  But do I need to download a client separately?  I'm trying to access MySQl in terminal to create an account or login but nothing is working.

Comment: Usually the client ("mysql") is included with the server packages. What does "nothing is working" mean?

Comment: well, In terminal, I tried doing `% mysql -p -u` to try to create a user, but getting bash command not found error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the full path to mysql (/var/lib/mysql), or add the mysql directory to your $PATH var.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to install LAMP environment on your mac, try a complete solution, such as MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or XAMP.

These tools are bundled with phpmyadmin, which makes mysql administration easy